# Grid with some columns attached to the edge

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to figure out how to create such a grid where some columns of the rows can go to the edge of the screen, but at the same time it follows the alignment with all other blocks. Also all that should stack block after block on mobile.
I can't figure out from where I should start... Would be super happy if someone would point me to some sources or clues how to achive this!

Thanks and happy friday everyone!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative `margin` to make this grid alignment.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
}

p:nth-child(7) {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! That looks pretty good, but I'm thinking how I can combine it with some css grids (f.e. bootstrap or any other one) to get the same positioned elements all over website? Is it possible to do it with some responsive grid systems?

Comment: I bet you if you play around with it you will find a solution by using `position` and `media queries :)